# How do I prove that this is or isn't isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory

$\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \cong \mathbb{Z}_6$?

How can I show that the groups are isomorphic? (Or not?)

Comment: In general, $\mathbb Z_m\times \Bbb Z_n \cong \Bbb Z_{mn}$ iff $(m,n)=1$. I'm sure this has been asked many times here before.

Comment: For example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795919/mathbb-z-mn-isomorphic-to-mathbb-z-m-times-mathbb-z-n).

Comment: But Z2 X Z2 is not isomorphic to Z4, as Z4 is cyclic and Z2 is not....

Comment: @lifeofjuds $(2,2) \not = 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to construct an isomorphism between the two groups why not start by listing the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ and figuring out if any of them have order $6$? If you can find one then it generates a cyclic subgroup of order $6$ (a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6$) inside your group of order $6$ .

Comment: I made a table of all of the 36 elements in ℤ2 × ℤ3, but I don't know how to figure out if any of them have order 6. How do I do that?

Comment: You have too many elements in $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$. There are only 6, have you looked at the other question at all?